# How can I add a collection navigation property onto a derived entity with no discriminator?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, discriminator, entity-framework-core-3.0

I have a database with two tables, `Fruit` and `Crate`.  `Crate` has a foreign key referencing the `Fruit` table.

I have a library, `LibraryA`, with a `DbContext` (`DbContextBase`), and a model, `Fruit`.

I have a second project which references `LibraryA` and contains its own `DbContext` (`DbContextExtended`) extended from `DbContextBase`, along with the `Crate` entity.

For ease of working with the code, I want to add collection navigation property (`ICollection<Crate> Crates`) to the `Fruit` entity, but I can't do this in `LibraryA` so I create a derived class in the second project:

```
public partial class Fruit : LibaryA.Models.Fruit
{
    public Fruit()
    {
        Crates = new HashSet<Crate>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Crate> Crates { get; set; }
}
```

Even without adding it to `DbContextExtended` and configuring it, I get the following exception at runtime:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The discriminator value for 'Fruit' is 'Fruit' which is the same for 'Fruit'. Every concrete entity type in the hierarchy needs to have a unique discriminator value.'

However, these two `Fruit` models are for the same table, and the same records, so there is no field to discriminate between them.

For the purpose of this example, assume that I cannot move `Crate` into `LibraryA`.

Is what I want with a derived collection navigation property achievable?

Comment: What about making Fruit in LibraryB a partial class from Fruit in LibraryA and putting them both in the same namespace?

Comment: @JoostK I'm not sure that would be the most maintainable of solutions, however I'm afraid it's a moot point anyway as you cannot have a partial class spanning across multiple assemblies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods

Comment: I did not realise it wasn't possible but it makes total sense it isn't. The only other thing I can think off which isn't what you want but technically semi-solves the issue. Is defining an extension method inside libraryB

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I had the same exception...
It turns out that the base class was accidently used in DbContext instead of the derived.